# Wix Velo - hiding elements from members with multiple roles

Tags: velo

I've looked everywhere but I couldn't find a working answer for my problem - in Wix Velo I'd like to hide the element *#image1* from every site member except for members who have the role *Gardener* among their roles.
I have a code, but it doesn't work anymore if the member has other roles aside from the Gardener role assigned to them (for example, if the member has both *Gardener* role and *Florist* role).

I think the "firstRole" thing is the problem here, but even if it is, I have no idea how to fix it.
What would the solution be?
Thank you in advance!

*I know that this works when a member only has one role assigned to them (Gardener):*

```js
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

$w.onReady(function () {
    var roleName;
    let currentUser = wixUsers.currentUser;

    currentUser.getRoles()
        .then((roles) => {
            var firstRole = roles[0];
            roleName = firstRole.name;
            if (roleName === 'Gardener') {
                $w('#image1').show();
            } else {
                $w('#image1').hide();
            }
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code issue arises because it only checks a user's first role. If "Gardener" isn't first among multiple roles, the user isn't recognized as a Gardener. Modify the code to check if "Gardener" is present in any of the user's roles.

Try this:

```js
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

$w.onReady(function () {
    let currentUser = wixUsers.currentUser;

    currentUser.getRoles()
        .then((roles) => {
            // Check if any of the roles is 'Gardener'
            const isGardener = roles.some(role => role.name === 'Gardener');

            if (isGardener) {
                $w('#image1').show();
            } else {
                $w('#image1').hide();
            }
        });
});
```

Here's what the modified code does:

Uses the `Array.prototype.some` method to check if any role in the user's roles array has the name "Gardener".
If isGardener is true, it shows `#image1`. If it's false, `#image1` is hidden.
This approach ensures that even if "Gardener" is not the first role in the list, as long as the user has it among their roles, `#image1` will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works exactly as I needed :)

Comment: I'm really happy for you. Wishing you a smooth and successful development process ahead!